# MongoDB: count of array elements in whole collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have following documents in my collection :

```json
{
    "id" : 1,
    "tags" : ["tag1","tag2","tag3"]
},
{
    "id" : 2,
    "tags" : ["tag1","tag4","tag5"]
},
{
    "id" : 3,
    "tags" : ["tag1","tag5","tag6"]
},
...
```

I want to know how many times same array elements appears in the collection:

```json
{
     "tag": "tag1",
     "count": 3
},
{
     "tag": "tag2",
     "count": 1
},
...
```

Is there a way to get this output in one aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$unwind` in a situation like this.
here is the referene [link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$tags" },
    { $group: {
        _id: "$tags",
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
])
```